# Solutions to $\sin x = \sin y$ in $0 \leq x \leq 2\pi$

Tags: trigonometry

How can I find the solutions to solutions to $\sin x = \sin y$ in $0 \leq x \leq 2\pi$.

If (for instance) $0 \leq x \leq \pi/2 $ then $\sin x = \sin (x+\pi/2)$ but thos doesnt work when $\pi/2 \leq x \leq \pi $ in this case $\sin x = -\sin (x+\pi/2)$

Comment: Hint. Draw the graph of the $\sin$ function. Find out where horizontal lines cross that graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the diagram below.

[image: symmetry_diagram_for_sine_and_cosine]

Two angles have the same sine if the $y$-coordinates of the points where their terminal sides intersect the unit circle are equal.  By symmetry, $\sin\theta = \sin\varphi$ if $\varphi = \theta$ or $\varphi = \pi - \theta$.  Any angle coterminal with these angles will also have the same sine.  In general, $\sin\theta = \sin\varphi$ if 
$$\varphi = \theta + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
or 
$$\varphi = \pi - \theta + 2m\pi, m \in \mathbb{Z}$$
Observe that if $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$, then $0 \leq \pi - \theta \leq \pi$.  Thus, for $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$, $\sin\theta = \sin\varphi \implies \varphi = \theta$ or $\varphi = \pi - \theta$.

If $\pi < \theta \leq 2\pi$, $0 > \pi - \theta \geq -\pi$, so we must add $2\pi$ to $\pi - \theta$ to find an angle in $[0, 2\pi]$ that has the same sine as $\theta$.  Hence, if $\pi < \theta < 2\pi$, $\sin\theta = \sin\varphi \implies \varphi = \theta$ or $\varphi = 3\pi - \theta$.