# Why does this way of solving $\sin(x)+\cos(x)=0$ give no solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm trying to solve $\sin(x)+\cos(x)=0$. I solved it using other methods and got the result $x=\frac{3\pi}{4}+\pi k$. However, I tried to verify that other methods also work and the following method yielded result that there are no solutions for the equation, which is obviously incorrect. Could someone tell me why is that?
$$\sin(x)=-\cos(x)=-\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{2})=\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi)=\sin(x+\frac{3 \pi}{2})$$
$$x=x + \frac{3 \pi}{2} + 2 \pi k, k \in Z$$
$$0=\frac{3 \pi}{2} + 2 \pi k$$, which is untrue for any integer value of $k$. Why doesn't this method give any of the solutions that exist?

Comment: Tip: Write `$\sin x$` for $\sin x$.

Comment: There are other ways for sine to take the same value besides the arguments differing by $2\pi$.

Comment: The sine function is not one-to-one, hence there is no reason to expect that $\sin(x) = \sin(y)$ implies that $x = y$.  In addition to the periodicity of the sine function, consider points on the unit circle which are the same height above or  below the horizontal axis.

Comment: Should I then cosider $x = \pi-x-\frac{3 \pi}{2}$? This way I do arrive at the correct solution. But should I always consider this possibility when solving equations like this?

Comment: So if I have $sin(x)=sin(y)$ then I should consider $x = y + 2 \pi k$ and $x = \pi - y + 2 \pi k$?

Comment: And if $cos x = cos y$ then either $x = y + 2 \pi k$ or $x = -y + 2 \pi k$

Comment: @РоманКирьянов You seem to be approaching this very *procedurally*, as though you want a procedure that is always going to work, no matter what.  While the procedure you have suggested is appropriate, it would be far better to take a step back and try to understand the objects you are working with.  What does it *mean* to say that $sin(x) = y$? or that $\sin(\theta) = \sin(\varphi)$?  How are these functions defined?  Is there some underlying geometry which might be helpful?  *Think* about the problem.

Comment: The way I think about the problem is that two angles $x$ and $y$ can have the same sin if they make the same angle with the x-axis when drawn on the unit circle. That happens in two cases: if they are the same or if they are in relationship $x=\pi - y$. I forgot about the second possibility when I was solving the equation.

Comment: Точно.  It helps to have a picture in mind when working with trig functions.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Спасибо!

Comment: If this post gets reopened, I suggest to reclose it but for a new reason: not for the (arguable) "lack of context" but as a duplicate, of for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2173721